# how to do autocomplete in jsf primefaces via my database coloumn name which is user

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Hi I am stuck at autocomplete when I search autocompleted 
method most of the website showing example by static adding 
list method, but what I wanted is I have a table called User
 and this usernames ı want to make them show on my searchbox   any help would be appreciate

My User JDBC

```
public List<User> getAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> userList = null;
        DBConnectionHelper dbConn = DBConnectionHelper.getInstance();
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement psSelectUser = null;
        try {

            userList = new ArrayList<>();
            conn = dbConn.getConnection();

            psSelectUser = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM eFaturaPortal.users");

            ResultSet rs = psSelectUser.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                userList.add(new User(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getBoolean(4), rs.getBoolean(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getLong(8)));
            }

            psSelectUser.close();
            return userList;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserDBHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return userList;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    dbConn.closeConnection(conn);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

My User Entity:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    private boolean activated;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private long defaultOrganisationId;

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(Long id, String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean activated, String name, String surname, long defaultOrganisationId)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.activated = activated;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.defaultOrganisationId = defaultOrganisationId;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean getEnabled()
    {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean getActivated()
    {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated)
    {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname)
    {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public long getDefaultOrganisationId()
    {
        return defaultOrganisationId;
    }

    public void setDefaultOrganisationId(long defaultOrganisationId)
    {
        this.defaultOrganisationId = defaultOrganisationId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "tr.com.java.efaturaportal.entity.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ClientSupplier> getClientSuppliersCollection() {
        return clientSuppliersCollection;
    }

    public void setClientSuppliersCollection(Collection<ClientSupplier> clientSuppliersCollection) {
        this.clientSuppliersCollection = clientSuppliersCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ClientSupplier> getClientSuppliersCollection1() {
        return clientSuppliersCollection1;
    }

    public void setClientSuppliersCollection1(Collection<ClientSupplier> clientSuppliersCollection1) {
        this.clientSuppliersCollection1 = clientSuppliersCollection1;
    }

}
```

My User Interface

```
public List<User> getAllUsers();
```

My UserManager

```
 @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> result;

        try {
            result = m_userHelper.getAllUsers();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My UserList.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">
            <h3>Kullanıcılar</h3>        
            <h:form id="userSearchForm">
                <h:panelGroup id="results" class="table-responsive">

                    <p:dataTable id="userListTable" var="tableUser" value="#{userListBean.users}"
                                 selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{tableUser.username}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom">

                        <p:column headerText="Kullanıcı Adı" style="text-align: center;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableUser.username}" />
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: Off-topic: Using JPA makes your code cleaner... On-topic: What is the 'problem'?

Comment: I like to add dynamic autocomplete in JSF primefaces want to use my user coloumn from my database

Comment: Yes and I'd like a lot of money.... What you'd like is not what the 'problem is... You have code above... does that work? Most likely not... Please be specific on what goes wrong... There is not even an autoComplete in the code... [mcve]... please...

Comment: yes the code is working fine and I tried autocompleted that did not work